# Is there any way to convert .unr file?

Tags: maps, unreal, file-format

I'd like to examine a Harry Potter game for study purposes.
All of resources are fine except map file. 
The maps are in a `.unr` file format. I know it is unreal map file.

Is there any way to convert `.unr` file to `.fbx`, `.obj`, or `pskx` formats?
I want to open map file to 3ds max or blender.

Comment: Do you want to modify only the map mesh?

Comment: mesh and texture